# How to store the file path locally using local storage in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, iframe

I tried `$localstorage` to store the file path locally and preview the file using `iframe` but I am getting error.

```
$scope.getResume = function() {

            var resumeJson = {
                    "json":{
                        "request":{
                            "candidateid":$rootScope.globals.currentUser.userId,
                            "type":2
                        }
                    }
               };


    var getresume = "http://MyServerURL?request=" + JSON.stringify(resumeJson);

    $scope.resume = $localStorage.$default({x: getresume});
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<iframe id="resume" src="{{resume.x}}" style="margin-top: 2em; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
```

But I am getting error and its showing error message inside frame as:

> Cannot GET /%7B%22json%22:%7B%22request%22:%7B%22candidateid%22:44,%22type%22:2%7D%7D%7D

When I tried to inspect the page I found `iframe src = "{"json":{"request":{"candidateid":44,"type":2}}}"` instead of my URL.

Comment: Can you try to do something like: `$localStorage['file'] = "http://MyServerURL?request=" + JSON.stringify(resumeJson);` And then `$scope.resume = $localStorage['file'];` And in your view: `src="{{resume}}"`. I mean - try to test it without `default`. Or even `$scope.resume = "http://MyServerURL?request=" + JSON.stringify(resumeJson);`

Comment: I am using $sce in my another function. So my function throws error "angular.js:9997 Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{resume}}
Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.  URL: http://MyServerURL?request={"json":{"request":{"candidateid":44,"type":2}}}"

Comment: Then you should wrap your url in `$sce`

Comment: I used as "$scope.model.getresume = "http://prod1.groupz.in:7070/JobzTop/GetFile?request=" + JSON.stringify(resumeJson);     $scope.model.resume =  $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.model.getresume);               <iframe id="resume" src="{{model.resume}}" style="margin-top: 2em; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>"                Its now getting downloaded instead of preview. If I don't stringify the JSON then it consider as Object. How can I show the resume instead of downloading

Answer (score 0):

Look, I've wrote a Plunker for you. It's 100% working solution to dynamically set iFrame src.

https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:CR2TtS1zz9wFGgsl5z2c?p=preview

Maybe you should just change `src` to `ng-src`.

```
<iFrame ng-src="{{mc.resume}}"></iFrame>
```